# Type-safe template variable substitution

Tags: ocaml, template-engine

I had this idea of a type-safe templating language that would use polymorphic variants as a source of type-safe variables that can be substituted for text, for example:

```
type 'a t = Var of 'a | Text of string | Join of 'a t * 'a t  

let rec render ~vars = function
  | Text source -> source
  | Var label -> vars label
  | Join (left, right) -> render left ~vars ^ render right ~vars

let result = render (Join (Var `Foo, Text "bar")) ~vars:(function `Foo -> "foo");;

let () = assert (result = "foobar")
```

This is all fine: compiler will enforce that you don't forget a substitution variable, or that you don't have a typo in a variable name—thanks to polymorphic variants.

However, I find two problems:

1. You can accidentally supply an unused variable.
2. If template contains no variables, you are still forced to supply a `~vars` function, and the only one that would work would be `fun _ -> ""` or `fun _ -> assert false`, which compromizes type-safety in case the template ever changes.

I'm looking for advice on the problems above, but I also appreciate any applicable advice on API design.

Comment: What about `Var of 'a * 'a -> string`? That looks ugly, but you have to associate a printer for a variable. My solution here is to associate them in type constructor.

Comment: @nnarklrh not sure I follow. What is this `'a -> string` printer? Can you give an example?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. It should be `Var of 'a * string`. Then, you write "Var (`Foo, Foo)". But it seems too cumbersome.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing force you to always use polymorphic variants. you could have a `void` type that is guaranteed to be different to every polymorphic variant.

```
type void
let empty_vars : void -> string = fun _ assert false
```

When you apply it to an empty template, you end up with

```
let result = render (Text "bar") ~vars:empty_vars
```

That way, if you later add a variable to your template, you will immediately notice it through the type error.

For unused variables, the best I can suggest is also not to use polymorphic variants:

```
type v = Foo
let result = render (Join (Var Foo, Text "bar")) ~vars:(function Foo -> "foo");;
```

This will only catch unused cases in the function definition, but of course if you remove a part of your template, you won't notice anything.

One other solution that have similar properties but may, or may not suit your taste is to use objects.

```
let rec render ~vars = function
  | Text source -> source
  | Var label -> label vars
  | Join (left, right) -> render left ~vars ^ render right ~vars


let foo v = v#foo
let result = render (Join (Var foo, Text "bar")) ~vars:object method foo = "foo" end
```

That way you can keep the same pattern when no variables are used:

```
let result = render (Text "bar") ~vars:object end
```

But still no unused variable check.

Comment: Your `empty_vars` solution is interesting. However, you need to remember to supply the function as `~vars`. I was thinking to make `~vars` default to `empty_vars`, but then it infers `render` to be `~vars:(void -> string) -> void t -> string` which is not useful. Any suggestions?

Comment: This is a classical problem to want default parameter to have a type that can be overridden, sadly there is currently no generic good solution for that (some have ideas on how to implement that in the compiler). Yet in that case you have a somewhat lightweight solution: declare two versions of your function : `render: vars:('a -> string) -> 'a t -> string` and `render': void t -> string`, `render'` being the one preapplied to `empty_vars`

Answer (score 1):

I think it is impossible with polymorphic variants. The type of `render` function is:

val render : var:('a -> string) -> 'a t -> string

and the partial application `` render (Join (Var `Foo, Text "var")) `` has the following type:

```
vars:([> `Foo ] -> string) -> string
```

What you want to do is to close the opened variant type `` [> `Foo ] `` and restrict it to `` [ `Foo ] -> string `` in order to exclude functions which can get larger inputs like `` [< `Foo | `Bar ] -> string ``.

The only way to restrict the type is to add a type constraint: `` (vars : [ `Foo ] -> string) ``, listing all the tags you want explicitly, but this is what you want to avoid...